# Change default MongoDB port on Ubuntu Snap installation

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I have installed MongoDB using using the following command using snap package manager.
`snap install mongo32;`

It's working fine. However, I want to change the port & I couldn't find **mongodb.conf** for this installation. I searched for it in the following locations:

```
/snap/mongo32  

/etc
```

Recursive `grep` search gave me the file which contains default port number(32017) for this installation in this file:

```
/snap/mongo32/2/command-mongod.wrapper
```

However, this file is read-only, and I assume that it is not a good idea to make changes to a read-only file. Please advice how should I change the default port for mongo32 snap installation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see in the snapcraft manifest file [here](https://github.com/niemeyer/snaps/blob/master/mongodb/mongo32/snapcraft.yaml#L28) that the default port number is hardcoded:

```
mongod:
    command: bin/run.sh mongod --port=32017 --smallfiles --noprealloc
```

The mongo snaps follow the convention mongoNN where NN is the port number NN017 (e.g. mongo33 will use the port 33017)

Comment: Do you mean that we can't change it ?
If yes, I suppose only these ports are allowed in snap installation: 
mongo22  mongo24  mongo26  mongo30  mongo32  mongo33

Comment: mongoNN also refers to the version (e.g. mongo33 is mongo version 3.3.x) . It doesn't look like you can configure the port with these particular mongo snaps so it might be best to fork it and modify it yourself, as well as update it to a more recent mongo version

Comment: Okay. That answers it, thanks!
Will do that :P Shouldn't be too difficult.